# Rails - assigning the foreign id at item creation between two related model objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-models

I am having difficulty successfully assigning the foreign key in a one-to-many relationship at the creation of one of the "many" model objects.

In more concrete terms... I have two models, `Course` and `Section`, in which **Course** `has_many :sections`, and each **Section** `belongs_to :course`.  Each **section**, among other attributes, has the foreign key `course_id`.

I would like to write a helper method called `current_course`, so that when I write my `create` function I could write `current_course.sections.build(params[:section])` which will automatically assign the foreign key `course_id` at creation.  In other words, `current_course` would take the id of the class that it was clicked from (i.e. `/class/1/`) and make equal to `course_id` of the newly created section.  I tried along the lines of `@current_course ||= Course.find(params[:course_id])`.. but it keeps on throwing an ID error at creation.   What am I doing wrong, and how do I correct my `current_course` method?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing looks basically correct.

Your `create` controller would generally have a line like this at the beginning. (You can't find something that hasn't been created after all.)

```
@course = Course.new(params[:course])
```

If you know that you're going to build exactly one `Section`, you might want to do `@course.sections.build` in your `new` controller. Then from there, make sure your `Courses` model `accepts_nested_attributes_for :sections` then you can fill in the `Section` fields in your view with the `fields_for` function. When you do it this way, your controller can simply say `@course.save` and the `Section` will be saved along with it.

I hope that helps, but if not then please add a comment with the error that you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks! Its likely that I would like users to create several sections for each course as they see fit, so not sure if the above may still be fully applicable. You mentioned nested attributes, and I have thought about nested resources (nice routes like `/course/1/section/2`, but since ultimately I have the foreign key in place for my **Section** model, I would still like to be able to show just `/section/2` and have it inherently linked to course with id=1.  I understand one alternative is to pass information between controllers to use :sessions, but was wondering if there is a better way?

Comment: Nested attributes are very different from nested routes. Basically, it would give you a `@course.sections_attributes=` function that would take an array of hashes that each represent a `Section` that will be associated with the `Course`. The biggest benefit though is how clean the controller becomes. The `:session` store is somewhat limited in size, so passing stuff through it is generally not a good idea.